# error: invalid use of incomplete type (Maybe a definition issue)

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and can't seem to get it right with all the templates and specializations. I think I'm missing a definition of the static function `internal_set_BC` but I'm not sure. When I compile the code below, I get the following error:

```
test.cc:37:49: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class RT<2, D>’
 static void RT<2, D>::internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t)
                                                 ^
test.cc:19:7: error: declaration of ‘class RT<2, D>’
 class RT: public BC<n, D>
       ^
test.cc:41:49: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class RT<3, D>’
 static void RT<3, D>::internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t)
                                                 ^
test.cc:19:7: error: declaration of ‘class RT<3, D>’
 class RT: public BC<n, D>
```

The simplified code is as follows:

```
class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class E {};

template <int n>
class Base
{};

template <int n, typename D>
class BC: public Base<n>
{
public:
  virtual void set_BC(D& d, A& a) =0;
  virtual void set_BC(D& d, B& b) =0;
};

template <int n, typename D> 
class RT: public BC<n, D>   
{ 
public: 
  void set_BC(D& d, A& a)
  {internal_set_BC(d, a);}
  void set_BC(D& d, B& b)
  {internal_set_BC(d, b);}
private:
  template <typename T> 
  static void internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t);   
};

template <typename D, typename T>
static void RT<2, D>::internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t)
{//code
}
template <typename D, typename T>
static void RT<3, D>::internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t)
{//code
}
```

Moreover, when I try to instantiate `internal_set_BC` with this code:

```
template void RT<2, C>::internal_set_BC(C& d, A& t);
```

I get this error:

```
test.cc:45:51: error: explicit instantiation of ‘static void RT<n, D>::internal_set_BC(D&, T&) [with T = A; int n = 2; D = C]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]
 template void RT<2, C>::internal_set_BC(C& d, A& t);
```

Which supports my suspicion of a missing definition I had on the above code.

Your help is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You can do such thing only for full specialization:

```
template <>
template <typename T>
static void RT<2, int>::internal_set_BC(int& d, T& t)
{//code
}
```

`int` is just example. You should write partial class specialization.

```
template<typename D>
class RT<2, D> : public BC<2, D>
{
// public functions set_BC.
private:
   template <typename T>
   static void internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t);
};

template <typename D>
template <typename T>
void RT<2, D>::internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t)
{//code
}
```

You can also write something like this, to specialize only `internal_set_BC`:

```
template<int n, typename D, typename Impl>
class RT_base : public BC<n, D>
{
public:
  void set_BC(D& d, A& a)
  {
     Impl::internal_set_BC(d, a);
  }
  void set_BC(D& d, B& b)
  {
     Impl::internal_set_BC(d, b);
  }
};

template <int n, typename D>
class RT: public RT_base<n, D, RT<n, D> >
{
   friend class RT_base<n, D, RT<n, D> >;
   template <typename T> 
   static void internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t);   
};

template<typename D>
class RT<2, D> : public RT_base<2, D, RT<2, D> >
{
   friend class RT_base<2, D, RT<2, D> >;
   template <typename T>
   static void internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t);
};

template <typename D>
template <typename T>
void RT<2, D>::internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t)
{//code
}
```

or more simple, without `CRTP`

```
template<int n, typename D>
class RT_Base : public BC<n, D>
{
protected:
   template<typename T>
   static void internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t);
};

template<typename D>
class RT_Base<2, D> : public BC<2, D>
{
protected:
   template <typename T>
   static void internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t);
};

template <typename D>
template <typename T>
void RT_Base<2, D>::internal_set_BC(D& d, T& t)
{//code
}

template<int n, typename D>
class RT : public RT_Base<n, D>
{
public:
  void set_BC(D& d, A& a)
  {
     this->internal_set_BC(d, a);
  }
  void set_BC(D& d, B& b)
  {
     this->internal_set_BC(d, b);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added partial specialization (2nd code paragraph) and I don't get the error any more. I wonder if there is a reference or a book that explains templates deeply such that it touches on these specialization issues as the one in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem in your code.
You have defined

```
virtual void set_BC(D& d, A& a) =0;
```

in `class BC` but then you have implemented (in `class RT`)

```
void set_BC(const D& d, A& a)
```

The extra `const` makes this second function not an override and hence RT is still abstract.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is a mistake I made when I was simplifying the code. I fixed it now.